# Type Scanner was not found

Tags: java, methods, java.util.scanner

I'm currently reading Blue Pelican Java to learn new things, I'm on lesson 7 that involves learing keyboard input of int, double and strings.

I'm using Ready to program java to run my programs also.
The error im receiving results from

```
Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
```

With the error "Type Scanner was not found" and on the second Scanner "A candidate for type Scanner was found. But was invalid and needs to be fixed before this type will compile"

I copied the code directly from the book upgraded my java looked around online and also tried

```
import java.util.Scanner.*;
```

with no success can anyone tell me what I'm missing or doing wrong?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lesson7
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your integer here");
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(3*i);

    }
}
```

Comment: You have an own class, called Scanner, right? In the same package?

Comment: This is my entire code that i was shown in the book, so i guess not

Comment: Works fine on [ideone](https://ideone.com/ntBDLo).

Comment: @plook No other classes in the project? Maybe from other lessons.

Comment: Is it possible that its because im using ready to program, is there another more up to date program i should use instead?

Comment: @Tom None it starts fresh on every chapter so far.

Comment: Can you please show us your project structure?

Comment: @User1123123 I don't understand what you mean by that?

Comment: Which IDE do you use? Btw 'import java.util.Scanner.*' is not correct. It should be 'import java.util.Scanner', but that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Tom my ide is Ready to program, I think that may be my problem.

Comment: As Tom said, Are you using any IDE say for example Eclipse.. Which JDK version are you using and  let us know other  java classes and packages that are part of your project.

Comment: Can you please try a different IDE? Like Eclipse, IntelliJ or BlueJ if you like an easy one.

Comment: Yes i will try to install a new ide and get back to you thanks!

Comment: @plook, just clean the project and rebuild.

Comment: Yess it works now with eclipse thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you are not using the correct jdk version. Scanner class is only available in JDK 1.5 or later.

Comment: My ide was way out dated thanks im now using eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I removed the class specifier public. As much i know this specifier for class is used only when the code you are writing is to be packaged. My code Worked fine with this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Lesson7{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your integer here");
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println(3*i);
    }
}
```